# Why did android studio change Nexus 6 to sdk gphone x86 arm?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, arm

[Here are the phones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du3lB.png)

[Here is the error message when I hover over the Nexus 6 phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AldC1.png)

"Not applicable for main.dart configuration"

Image system is R. API is 30. Flutter doctor says there are no issues.
Running on macOS Catalina. Android Studio 4.0.1.

How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 5):

Flutter in Android Studio doesn't use the regular Android Studio device selector (the one on the right that's grayed out) because you can also select iPhones as target, which Android Studio's selector cannot do. Disregard that device selector for Flutter development, it's not used. The first one alone determines the phone your Flutter app will run on.

`sdk_gphone_<architecture>` is the device fingerprint of an official Android emulator. Select your phone's fingerprint (it should be either "Nexus 6", or the Nexus 6's code name, which is "shamu") in the left dropdown menu instead to run it on that, or make sure you have no emulators running.